# saving schema of a keyspace using the Java driver of Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to save a keyspace schema.

The command that I would use, using the cqlsh interface would be:

```
"describe keyspace demo"
```

How can I do the same thing using the Java driver?

Comment: Save the schema to file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`DESCRIBE` is a cqlsh command, Java Driver don't have it.**

But you can get the schema from Java Driver from `KeyspaceMetadata`
Sample Code to get the full Schema of `ashraful_test` keyspace:

```
try (Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints("127.0.0.1").withCredentials("cassandra", "cassandra").build();) {
    System.out.println(cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace("ashraful_test").exportAsString());
}
```

Or

If you want to save the schema to file in linux command:

```
cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -e "DESC ashraful_test" > ashraful_test.cql
```

Here

```
-u username
-p password
-e command to execute
> ashraful_test.cql will save the command output to ashraful_test.cql file
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java driver does have an equivalent of cqlsh `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE` comamnd, it's [`KeyspaceMetadata.exportAsString()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.2/com/datastax/driver/core/KeyspaceMetadata.html#exportAsString--).